# vb.net chart with database column name as X

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I want to make chart in VB.net with my Database Column name AS X

i have this table

### LulusCount | GagalCount

10         | 20

how to make it to chart ?

ive try make chart with this table and succed

### name | value

a | 10

b | 20

c | 30

code

```
CMD = New SqlCommand("SELECT Jurusan,Peminat FROM peminat", conn)
DR = CMD.ExecuteReader

While DR.Read               
     myChart.Series("info").Points.AddXY(DR("name").ToString,DR("value").ToString)
            End While
            DR.Close()
            CMD.Dispose()
```

with a,b,c as X point .. but how about the column name as X?

Comment: so you want the name column be displayed as x???, not so clear what you need, and what you have tried

Comment: yes, i just want column name be displayed as x .. and the values is 10&20 ... i got this data because i use COUNT to get the table.

Comment: sql string that i use 

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Ket='LULUS' Then 1 ELSE 0 END) As LulusCount,SUM(CASE WHEN Ket='GAGAL' Then 1 Else 0 END) As GagalCount FROM keterangan